# Accessing UITabBarController's content view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a way to access the content view (shown as Custom content on the diagram) in order to change its frame?

[image: UITabBarController diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access to selected view controller's view in tab bar

```
UIView *view = tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
```

Access to second view controller's view in tab bar

```
UIView *view2 = [(UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] view];
```

Comment: How about changing content size? I mean i have placed a subview at top of tabBarController view. And I want selectedViewController view lays below this subview.